# Check many cells for data and report data if found

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get a formula that can search through many cells for data and report the data of that cell back

```
eks: J2() M2(Cake) R2() X2()
```

Is there an easy way to "loop" or search through these and to check if there is data?

Kinda like `=If(J2,M2,R2,X2, print value)` would be 'Cake'

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something simple:

```
=TRIM(J2&M2&R2&X2)
```

Comment: That worked great! But if i want to do the trim command but from another sheet in the same book, what do
Is there an command for eks: =sheetname!Trim(J2&M2&R2&X2)

Comment: no, it would be: `=TRIM(sheetname!J2&sheetname!M2&sheetname!R2&sheetname!X2)`